# Scrape Javascript variable from HTML source code and pass it to custom javascript variable in GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have an e-commerce website on Prestashop and, instead of a data layer, it creates a javascript variable called MBG to be used for Enhanced E-Commerce. For example, here's what it looks like on a checkout page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    var MBG = GoogleAnalyticEnhancedECommerce;
                    MBG.setCurrency('INR');
                    MBG.add({"id":"8241835-83697","name":"\"Arpenaz 50 Jr Socks\"","category":"\"socks\"","brand":"","variant":"\"UK 2.5-5 - EU 35-38\"","type":"typical","position":"0","quantity":"1","list":"order","url":"","price":"93.84"});MBG.addCheckout('0');MBG.addProductClick({"id":"8241835-83697","name":"\"Arpenaz 50 Jr Socks\"","category":"\"socks\"","brand":"","variant":"\"UK 2.5-5 - EU 35-38\"","type":"typical","position":"0","quantity":"1","list":"order","url":"","price":"93.84"});
                });</script> <script type="text/javascript">ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The issue however is that my Universal Analytics tags are not able to read this data. Hence I have two questions.

1) If I pass this data to a custom javascript variable and have my UA tag read the same, will it work?

2) If yes, how do I pass this data to a custom javascript variable?

3) If no, is there any way I can use this data to create a data layer variable?

I do not have any dev support to create data layers directly on the website so all changes will have to be made through GTM. I'm a complete beginner at all this so any help will be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

2) You are able to access java script variables through creating custom JavaScript variables as below:

[image]

1) Then you are able to use this GTM variable to pass through the Enhanced Ecommerce information through reading the information from a variable rather then the Data Layer, as below:

[image]